# SHAP TreeExplainer for RandomForest multiclass: what is shap_values[i]?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, random-forest, shap

I am trying to plot SHAP
This is my code `rnd_clf` is a `RandomForestClassifier`:

```
import shap 
explainer = shap.TreeExplainer(rnd_clf) 
shap_values = explainer.shap_values(X) 
shap.summary_plot(shap_values[1], X)
```

I understand that `shap_values[0]` is negative and `shap_values[1]` is positive.

But what about for multiple class RandomForestClassifier? I have the `rnd_clf` classifying one of:

> ['Gusto','Kestrel 200 SCI Older Road Bike', 'Vilano Aluminum Road Bike 21 Speed Shimano', 'Fixie'].

How do I determine which index of `shap_values[i]` corresponds to which class of my output?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> How do I determine which index of shap_values[i] corresponds to which class of my output?

`shap_values[i]` are SHAP values for i'th class. What is an i'th class is more a question of an encoding schema you use: `LabelEncoder`, `pd.factorize`, etc.

You may try the following as a clue:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder

labels = [
    "Gusto",
    "Kestrel 200 SCI Older Road Bike",
    "Vilano Aluminum Road Bike 21 Speed Shimano",
    "Fixie",
]
le = LabelEncoder()
y = le.fit_transform(labels)
encoding_scheme = dict(zip(y, labels))
pprint(encoding_scheme)
```

---

```
{0: 'Fixie',
 1: 'Gusto',
 2: 'Kestrel 200 SCI Older Road Bike',
 3: 'Vilano Aluminum Road Bike 21 Speed Shimano'}
```

So, eg `shap_values[3]` for this particular case is for `'Vilano Aluminum Road Bike 21 Speed Shimano'`

To further understand how to interpret SHAP values let's prepare a synthetic dataset for multiclass classification with 100 features and 10 classes:

```
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from shap import TreeExplainer
from shap import summary_plot

X, y = make_classification(1000, 100, n_informative=8, n_classes=10)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, random_state=42)
print(X_train.shape)
```

---

```
(750, 100)
```

At this point we have train dataset with 750 rows, 100 features, and 10 classes.

Let's train `RandomForestClassifier` and feed it to `TreeExplainer`:

```
clf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100, max_depth=3)
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
explainer = TreeExplainer(clf)
shap_values = np.array(explainer.shap_values(X_train))
print(shap_values.shape)
```

---

```
(10, 750, 100)
```

> 10  : number of classes. All SHAP values are organized into 10 arrays, 1 array per class.
> 750 : number of datapoints. We have local SHAP values per datapoint.
> 100 : number of features. We have SHAP value per every feature.

For example, for `Class 3` you'll have:

```
print(shap_values[3].shape)
```

---

```
(750, 100)
```

> 750: SHAP values for every datapoint
> 100: SHAP value contributions for every feature

Finally, you can run a sanity check to make it sure real predictions from model are the same as those predicted by `shap`.

To do so, we'll (1) swap the first 2 dimensions of `shap_values`, (2) sum up SHAP values per class for all features, (3) add SHAP values to base values:

```
shap_values_ = shap_values.transpose((1,0,2))

np.allclose(
    clf.predict_proba(X_train),
    shap_values_.sum(2) + explainer.expected_value
)
```

---

```
True
```

Then you may proceed to `summary_plot` that will show feature rankings based on SHAP values on a per class basis. For class 3 this will be:

```
summary_plot(shap_values[3],X_train)
```

[image]

Which is interpreted as follows:

> - For class 3 most influential features based on SHAP contributions are 44, 64, 17
> - For features 64 and 17 lower values tend to result in higher SHAP values (hence higher probability of the class label)
> - Features 92, 6, 53 are least influential out of 20 displayed

Comment: Is the final graph wrong? There are no feature 16, 59 and so on in it.

Comment: @dgg32 The final graph is right. By default only top 20 features are displayed. But you can change it,

Comment: The plot and interpretation are not aligned. You may update your interpretation. Features 44,64,17 are the most important ones.

Comment: @Hadij Thanks, corrected. It's strange for such an old question you're the first one to notice the discrepancy

Answer (score 0):

According to [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/slundberg/shap/issues/1252#issuecomment-857469497), the order of the `shap_values` list corresponds to your model's `.classes_` attribute. In the end you can plot stuff like:

```py
shap.summary_plot(shap_values, X_test.toarray(), feature_names=model.get_feature_names_out(), class_names=model.classes_)
```

Note that the `model` can be two different models if you use a pipeline, accessible via the `pipeline.named_steps` dict. Say, in NLP where you have a tokenizer step for `feature_names` (*i.e.* words/n-grams) and an ML model for classification (`class_names`).